# Angular 1.4.8 incompatible with IE11 - Object doesn't support property or method 'endsWith'

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11, handsontable

How can I get this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0pk793e/12/) using HAndsOnTable and Angular 1.4.8 to work with IE11? I get this error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'endsWith'

I'm not sure but I think the culprit is this line:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: It isnt working at all undepending on which browser you use. Please fix your JavaScript errors.

Comment: It works in latest chrome. I'd like to find out why it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: No your fiddle is not working. Its full of errors. e.g. `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TodoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`. or `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/r0pk793e/12/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: I can confirm, I'm on the latest version of Chrome and your code is throwing a load of errors.

Comment: It's based on this one, which works: https://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/ I'm not sure where the break is.

Comment: Please debug it and create a working example to make it reproduceable.

Comment: Your example fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/ works very well in IE11.

Comment: That's not mine. Unfortunately. I don't understand why that seems happy with the TodoCtrl function and mine doesn't.

Comment: You could ask a new question "Why is my fiddle not working".

Comment: I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369395/why-is-my-fiddle-not-working

Comment: Thanks m8, now I was able to fix your IE11 problem! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y5p1n1uz/1/) and I also fixed the IE11 error. Please not that `.endWith()` is not a valid function in IE. Once you added this function as a prototype you will be fine:

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
  String.prototype.endsWith = function(searchString, position) {
      var subjectString = this.toString();
      if (typeof position !== 'number' || !isFinite(position) || Math.floor(position) !== position || position > subjectString.length) {
        position = subjectString.length;
      }
      position -= searchString.length;
      var lastIndex = subjectString.indexOf(searchString, position);
      return lastIndex !== -1 && lastIndex === position;
  };
}
```

(taken from https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/endswith-issue-in-ie11/233838)

Comment: Thanks! What's weird is when I add your prototype.endsWith to my fiddle it works just fine, but in yours... When I change the values in the table the footer does not update.

Comment: I'll check this. stand by