# Why is my fiddle not working?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, jsfiddle

This is just broken and I can't figure out why. The TodoCtrl function appears unrecognised and yet there are many examples of this working.

https://jsfiddle.net/r0pk793e/15/

I have tried both:

```
angular.module('App', []).controller("Ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
```

And:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
```

All to no avail.

Comment: That's a lot of code to inspect. Have you tried using a different method?

Comment: The only error I'm getting in Chrome's console is: Error: Argument 'TodoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined. Though the controller name needs updating, it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change this:

```
angular.module('App', []).controller("Ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
```

To this:

```
angular.module('App', []).controller("TodoCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
```

And put information in your ng-app like so:

```
ng-app="App"
```

Comment: Awesome. Now I get the problem.